# php file won't render after htpasswd auth

Tags: php, nginx, .htpasswd

I am running magento on an nginx server. I decided to lock down a folder full of .php files using auth_basic and a htpasswd file. Without the auth, the php pages render and work fine. But after forcing the auth, when I go to the page I get the login prompt (which is good), I log in, and then the browser tries to download the php file. It refuses to render it. This is across multiple browsers (chrome, firefox, opera, ie). Any idea what I need to do to be able to have it password protected but still working? Thanks!

EDIT: .conf file auth setup

```
location ~^ /FOLDER/ {
    auth_basic                   "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file         /path/to/htpasswd/;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you setup a password? There is, obviously, the problem with the server's configuration. And when you download the 'php' file, do you have php code in it or the result of its run?

Comment: It has php code. The password was set up in the site's .conf file. Code snippet added above

Comment: When you do this way, it does not send the code to php interpreter (or, by other words, to another location for which php interpreter is set up, this is how nginx is working). Look at the example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576230/password-protect-backoffice-folder-in-nginx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nginx will not 'jump' to another location, so you have to add 'proxying' to the php interpreter's process inside of your protected location:

```
location ~^ /FOLDER {
    auth_basic                   "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file         /path/to/htpasswd/;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Change port or config to whatever you have in the other location of your config. There is another way with named locations, but I do not think that you need it here.